# Salesforce list view button layout option not available

Tags: listview, layout, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have custom object in salesforce and I want to override new button. I have created a List view button to add to the layout but List View Button Layout option is not available in the object manager. Why this option is not showing and how can I add the list view button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the custom object if you didn't select allow search when you create this object you cannot see search layout and list view layout options as well.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you force navigate to the setup page, for example steal another custom object's link to this menu (`/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/01ID0000000tyHo/AlohaSearchLayouts/view`) and swap with your object's ID. Compare with IDs shown in `select durableid, developername from entitydefinition where IsCustomizable = true`

Or try switching to Classic UI, maybe the option displays there. Bit weird but oh well.

But generally you'd do the overrides as just that, real overrides. You want a new separate way to create new objects or a true override? What do you see in "Buttons Links and Actions" -> New -> Edit?
[image]